# $f$ differentiable and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. , prove that $|f'(x)| \le \frac{A}{2}$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be differentiable on $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Also, we know $|f''(x)| \le A$ on $(0,1)$, prove that $|f'(x)| \le \frac{A}{2}$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$

I'm guessing I should use taylor expansion but have no idea how to start

Any hints/suggestions? thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the conditions given are correct? There is no clue on whether the function is twice differentiable.

Comment: yes, I'm sure...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Taylor. Rolle's Theorem guarantees a $c\in (0,1)$ s.t. $f'(c)=0$. Now use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for...

Comment: this seems correct, since $0<\frac{A}{2}$, but then why all the other information?

Comment: for all $x\in[0,1]$, not just an $x$

Comment: OK, I see, thanks

Comment: would appreciate a little elaboration, didn't quite got it and understood where you used $|f''(x)| \le A$

Comment: The fundamental theorem gives us that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $(0,1)$ here, right?